# Temp table in Azure SQL Server returns error on second insert in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a temp table declared in a stored procedure within an Azure SQL Server instance.

After declaring it with

```
WITH temp 
    (cols) AS 
    (SELECT * FROM goaltable 
    WHERE someCondition = true)
```

and utilizing it in a couple of `INSERT` statements, SQL Server returns an error on the second `INSERT` that `invalid object name 'temp'.`

Will I have to declare the table again before my second `INSERT` statement, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WITH` key word is used to initialise a CTE (Comman Table Expression), it is not a Temporary Table.

Temp Tables are prefixed with a pound sign `#` or `##`(Global Temp tables, google for the differences).

A CTE's scope is limited to the very first statement after the CTE has been initialised.

```
WITH CTE AS
 ( /* Your query here */)
 SELECT FROM CTE  --<-- Scope of above CTE
                    -- it maybe select , delete, update statement here

SELECT FROM CTE    --<-- this statement is out of scope 
                     -- this will return an error
```

**Temp Tables**

In your case if you want to create a temp table and use it on multiple places you would need to do something like this...

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp 
FROM goaltable 
WHERE someCondition = true
```

Now this #Temp table's scope is the connection in which it is created. You can select from it multiple times anywhere in this session.

for example the following queries will be executed without any errors as long as they are executed in the same connection.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM #Temp
SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

**Note**

Even though the scope of the temp table is your session, yet it is a good practice to drop temp tables once you are done working with them.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying! I find the T-SQL documentation kind of overwhelming for most things, but this answered my question perfectly.